# is index of normal subgroups of a group always 2?

Tags: group-theory

Is it necessary for every subgroup of a group to have an Index  2  with respect to the group for the the subgroup to be normal?

Answer (score 2):

No. For example, all subgroups of an Abelian group are normal, and they need not have index 2. On the other hand, all subgroups of index 2 are normal.